# HBase master won't start, Can't connect to hbase.rootdir

Tags: apache, hadoop, amazon-ec2, localhost, hbase

I'm trying to run HBase in a pseudo-distributed mode based on the setup on the apache website, but I'm having trouble configuring the hbase.root directory correctly.

This is how my configuration files look like:

**In Hadoop directory:**

conf/core-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.default.name</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:9001</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

conf/hdfs-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.replication</name>
    <value>1</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.support.append</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.datanode.max.xcievers</name>
    <value>4096</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

conf/mapred-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>

<!-- Put site-specific property overrides in this file. -->

<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>mapred.job.tracker</name>
    <value>localhost:9001</value>
  </property>
</configuration>
```

**In my HBase directory**

hbase-site.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="configuration.xsl"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright 2010 The Apache Software Foundation
 *
 * Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one
 * or more contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file
 * distributed with this work for additional information
 * regarding copyright ownership.  The ASF licenses this file
 * to you under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the
 * "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance
 * with the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
 *
 *     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
 *
 * Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
 * distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
 * WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
 * See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
 * limitations under the License.
 */
-->
<configuration>

  <property>
    <name>dfs.support.append</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.rootdir</name>
    <value>hdfs://localhost:9000/hbase</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.cluster.distributed</name>
    <value>true</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>hbase.zookeeper.quorum</name>
    <value>localhost</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

When I run the start-hbase.sh script it says that it starts zookeeper, hbase master and region server and i'm able to log in to them. I can then access the hbase shell, but I can't create tables or anything. I tried to connect to the master-status ui using my web browser, but it wouldn't connect. At first I thought it was because I was running it on an amazon instance and that port 9000 wasn't granted permission, but I found it was. Ports 50030, and 50070 are granted the same permissions ans I'm able to access the job tracker and namenode from them. I checked the logs and found this error:

```
2013-08-05 18:00:35,613 INFO org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client: Retrying connect to server: localhost/127.0.0.1:9000. Already tried 9 time(s); retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime=1 SECONDS)
2013-08-05 18:00:35,616 FATAL org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster: Unhandled exception. Starting shutdown.
java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1136)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC.getProxy(RPC.java:411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.createRPCNamenode(DFSClient.java:135)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:276)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient.<init>(DFSClient.java:241)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DistributedFileSystem.initialize(DistributedFileSystem.java:100)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:1411)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:66)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:1429)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:254)
    at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:187)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.util.FSUtils.getRootDir(FSUtils.java:667)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.MasterFileSystem.<init>(MasterFileSystem.java:112)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.finishInitialization(HMaster.java:560)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.master.HMaster.run(HMaster.java:419)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
    at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:708)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.SocketIOWithTimeout.connect(SocketIOWithTimeout.java:206)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:511)
    at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:481)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupConnection(Client.java:453)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.setupIOstreams(Client.java:579)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client$Connection.access$2100(Client.java:202)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.getConnection(Client.java:1243)
    at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1087)
    ... 17 more
```

As you can see it's trying to access localhost/127.0.0.1:9000, which is obviously wrong.:

> Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:9000 failed on connection exception

This is what my /etc/hosts file looks like:

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

**Also:**
Replacing localhost with the public DNS of the instance doesn't work either

Comment: Hadoop and HBase versions?And why do you think trying to connect to localhost is wrong?

Comment: hadoop: 1.1.2 and hbase 0.94.10, which based on the chart on their website are compatible: http://hbase.apache.org/book/configuration.html#hadoop,

and I'm not saying connecting to localhost is wrong, but localhost/127.0.0.1 wouldn't that be like connecting to www.stackoverflow/stackoverflow.com?

Comment: But you want to do that. I can see localhost in your config files. If you don't want to use it then you need to use proper hostname in the config files.

Comment: [enter link description here][1]

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065089/hbase-master-wont-start-cant-connect-to-hbase-rootdir
  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18065089/hbase-master-wont-start-cant-connect-to-hbase-rootdir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Few suggestions first. You don't actually need to put **dfs.replication**, **mapred.job.tracker** in core-site.xml and **dfs.support.append** in hbase-site.xml files. It's not required.

Please make sure NN is running fine and is out of safemode. Also, it's better to turn IPv6 off and add **hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir** and **hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort** in hbase-site.xml file and set export **HBASE_MANAGES_ZK** in hbase-env.sh to **true**. Restart HBase after changing config files.

Comment: The namenode is running, I'm not sure how to check whether it's in safe mode or not. What should I set as the value for **hbase.zookeeper.property.dataDir** and **hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort**?

Comment: You can check that through the HDFS web ui or through the HDFS shell using **bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode enter**. Create a dir at some convenient location, say your home and use it for dataDir and use 2181 for clientPort.

Comment: Apologies. Use this : **bin/hadoop dfsadmin -report**. Please ignore bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode enter. This commend is used to enter into the safemode. Use bin/hadoop dfsadmin -safemode leave if safemode is on.

Comment: ok, that worked, apparently I had changed the configuration of hadoop and forgot to reformat the namenode. Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. As a side note, it's always better to have **dfs.data.dir** and **dfs.name.dir** in your **hdfs-site.xml**. These properties default to /tmp directory which get emptied at each restart. As a result you'll loose all your data and metadata causing a reformat everytime you restart your machine. You might wanna visit these links http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/07/how-to-configure-hadoop.html#.UgABC2T08Vk ... http://cloudfront.blogspot.in/2012/06/how-to-configure-habse-in-pseudo.html#.UgABD2T08Vk , in case you need some help. I have tried to explain all this in detail. HTH

Comment: Thanks, I was bound to ask about that eventually.